# Graphing and solving logarithmic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am trying to solve these questions:

**1. $8^x=4$**

$\log 8^4 = x$ and this becomes $4\log 8$

$\log 8 = \log 2^3 = 3\log 2$ so  it finally becomes $12 \log 2$

**2. $4e^{2x} = 91$**

$(e^{x})^{2} = \frac{91}{4}$

$e^x = \frac{\sqrt{91}}{2}$

$x = \ln \frac{\sqrt{91}}{2}$

**3. $\log (x+4)-\log x = \log (x+2)$**

$\log\frac{x+4}{x} = \log(x+2)$

$10^{\log\frac{x+4}{x}} = 10^{x+2}$

$\frac{x+4}{x} = x+2$

$x = \frac{-1\pm \sqrt{17}}{2}$

**4. $\log_4 x - \log_4 (x-1) = \frac{1}{2}$**

$4^{\log_4 \frac{x}{x-1}} = 4^{1/2}$

$\frac{x}{x-1} = 2$

$x = 2$

**5. $\frac{3000}{e^{2x} +2} = 2$**

$3000= 2e^{2x}+4$

$1498 = e^{2x}$

$\ln 1498 = 2x $

$x = \frac{\ln1498}{2}$

Are these answers correct?

Also can someone please show me how to graph these problems? I know that there are a lot but maybe just how to graph number 5 or number 4. Or just provide me with a hint so i can graph them myself.

Thank you!

Comment: Q.1 The answer should be $2/3$. It is $\log 8^x=\log 4$, not $\log 8^4=x$. Q.3 You should reject the negative root.

Comment: thank you! are those the only two incorrect? also could you help with how to graph number 4 or 5

Comment: The other three are correct. You may use Desmos to draw the graphs. https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Comment: i need to know how to sketch the graphs though